# How can I debug program linking specific version of shared library?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, cross-platform, glibc, libc

helloworld.c:

```
int main(){}
```

[1]    9845 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  LD_PRELOAD=./libc.so.6 ./helloworld

This preload libc is an old version of glibc

Can I debug helloworld linking it on my system?

Or is there a fast way to deploy a virtual machine with the specific version of shared libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I debug helloworld linking it on my system?

Yes, but you need to do it correctly. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) provides details, and an explanation for why your `LD_PRELOAD` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

- From your post I could see POC dumping core. So, better use gdb to analyze the coredump and see the crashing callstack. Make sure you load the right libc in gdb while analyzing coredump.
- Else use LD_DEBUG=all before invoking POC and see if any pointers to crash by seeing the details during runtime.

Comment: Sorry I misled you. POC dumping core? No. I ran vulnerable. I didn't ran POC. And I just understand it's not about POC at all. I updated my post. Thank you!